# Passing in vars for use in conditionals in Low Variables

Tags: low-variables

Is there a simple way to create a custom conditional a bit like this:

In the template:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="footer" foo="bar"}
```

In the variable:

```
   {if foo == "bar"}
      Show something here
   {/if}
```

I've played around with preload_replace a bit but no joy so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `preparse:my_var` parameter, available only in the [Textarea variable type](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/types#textarea). Example:

```
{exp:low_variables:single var="my_var" preparse:foo="bar"}
```